# Why is a Cookie not sent to API endpoint on API host machine only?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, cookies, cors

My API has authentication endpoint A which should return an authentication cookie. Endpoint B requires the authentication cookie. After visiting endpoint A, both my dev machine and a separate test client machine always authenticate successfully when visiting endpoint B (on the live VM, localhost is not involved) in Chrome. I can see the **cookie** header in those requests to endpoint B.

Meanwhile, when visiting the live endpoint B from the hosting VM itself, authentication appears successful, yet Chrome is redirected when attempting to visit endpoint B. Logging indicates the auth cookie is not being sent in the request to endpoint B.

Both my dev machine and the VM get the **set-cookie** header in response when using Postman (I have to disable SSL verification on both machines for this to work).

The cookie looks like this, though I've tried it without the domain, secure, and samesite policy also (incrementally):

```
cName=cValue; expires=Tue, 11 Jun 2019 02:21:06 GMT; domain=.mydomain.net; path=/; secure; samesite=lax
```

**Question:** What could prevent Chrome on the VM from sending the cookie?  I've tried adjusting the cookie's attributes in case that was the issue.

**Context**:

- asp.net core version: 2.2
- Cookie.httpOnly: false
- Cookie.SameSite: I've tried None and Lax because the cookie is requested from a chrome extension.
- Cookie.Secure: I've tried true and false.
- Cookie.Domain: I've tried multiple values and not setting it.
- CORS is used and wide open.
- I have a trusted SSL certificate installed for the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to learn some CORS things to accomplish my goal. I found a very helpful [msdn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2). In short, the following client and server changes were required in order to satisfy the browser and accept requests as needed on the server.

This was causing my immediate issue:

- XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials had to be set to true on the client side in order to not ignore the auth cookie in a response [(paragraph 2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials).
- CorsPolicyBuilder.AllowCredentials() had to be called in Configure() in Startup.cs in order to receive that withCredentials request.

What's strange is that without that, it works just fine everywhere except the hosting server and I still cannot explain that.

Other pesky details I needed to get correct that could have clouded the issue:

- The Cookie's domain must be set appropriately for the use case
- The Cookie's SameSite attribute had to be Lax
- UseCors()
- CorsPolicyBuilder.WithOrigins(new string[] {"domain-a","domain-b"})